# Lisp good practices

Tags: algorithm, lisp, common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

I've started studying Lisp 2 days ago and I'm reading Paul Graham's ANSI Common List, which exposes the language structure in a very interesting way. It's not too much theoretical for beginners, and not too shallow (as Sierra-Bate's Head First Java, which personally I hate). After a brief general language introduction, he starts talking bout lists and raise an example of simple list compression. Basically, let el be an element which is repeated n times. You replace all of them by a single (n el) list. To do this he gave an code implementation, but I tried to do my own, which apparently is working. I'd like if possible, that someone analyses my code and show me the critical points of its implementation, which I'm sure there is a lot, since it's my first contact with Lisp. Thank u all!

```
(defun compress (x)
"compress a list replacing repeated sequential values for (<n> <value>)"
(let ((lst '()) (fst t) (lt nil) (n 0)) 
    (dolist (el x)
        (if fst
            (progn
                (setq fst nil)
                (setq lt el)
                (setq n 1))
            (progn 
                (if (equal el lt)
                    (setq n (+ n 1))
                    (progn
                        (setq lst (cons (if (= n 1)
                                    lt
                                    (list n lt)) 
                                lst))
                        (setq lt el)
                        (setq n 1)
                    )))))
    (setq lst (cons (if (and (not (= n 0)) (= n 1))
                        lt
                        (list n lt)) 
            lst))
(reverse lst)))
```

Comment: You may also be interested in Peter Seibel's [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Comment: `(compress nil)` yields `((0 nil))`, which seems weird.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using this literature as well, it's a good one too. But didn't find a pdf version there, just the Tex files, which are a bit confusing and I couldn't compile it. If u have an idea how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: @StanislavKondratyev good catch. A nil check at input woudn't be bad idea, actually it's necessary since my algorithm adds the last item outside the list-loop. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm seems quite reasonable.  I only find the `fst` variable superfluous.  You use it only when entering the loop, so you could just as well move the first bunch of assignments to the preamble and iterate over the rest elements of the list.

Now the question is how to express the algorithm in Lisp.

The most significant point is that you can use `nreverse` instead of `reverse`.  `nreverse` is more efficient, but it destroys the structure of its argument.  Generally, you don't want that because of so-called shared structure: a cons cell can be a part of a few lists, so modifying a cons sell you can bring about unexpected changes in apparently unrelated lists.  (PCL treats this issue very well.)  However, in your function you construct `lst` from scratch, manually pushing new elements onto it, so there is no way it could share structure with other lists.  So you can safely dispense with the structure.  This is the common `push/nreverse` idiom.  `reverse` just conses up a new list, and `lst` becomes garbage.

To make the code more idiomatic, you could use standard shortcuts like `incf` for `+=` and `push` for `cons=`.  Nowadays the universal `setf` seems to be more popular then `setq`.  Personally, I prefer using `cond` where a `progn` would otherwise appear.  So you could end up with something like this:

```
(defun compress (x)
  "compress a list replacing repeated sequential values for (<n> <value>)"
  (if x
      (let ((lst '())
            (lt (first x))
            (n 1)) 
        (dolist (el (rest x))
          (cond ((equal el lt) (incf n))
                (t (push (if (= n 1)
                             lt
                             (list n lt))
                         lst)
                   (setf lt el)
                   (setf n 1))))
        (push (if (= n 1)
                  lt
                  (list n lt))
              lst)
        (nreverse lst))
      nil))
```

Comment: it's clear to me which takes nreverse to be faster than reverse, but I'm still a little unaccustomed to Lisp variable scope, I really got to take a deeper reading about this topic. Anyway I'll run some tests with these and another codes I have to the same function and submit them to large amount of data, then I tell u the result. Thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Stanislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970088/124319)
I would like to show another possible implementation.
The compression algorithm is a perfect use-case for  [`REDUCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm), also known as [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).
The reducing function takes the result so far, a new element, and combines them to produce the next result. The result you want is a list of couples. The initial element is the empty list.

```lisp
(defun compress (sequence)
  (reduce (lambda (number list &aux (head (first list)))
            (if (eql number (first head))
                (prog1 list
                  (incf (second head)))
                (cons (list number 1) list)))
          sequence
          :from-end t
          :initial-value nil))
```

Reduction is applied *from the end*, so that you can easily `cons` a new couple on top of the current result while keeping the existing order of elements. If your input is `'(a b b c)`, then the anonymous reducing function will be called as follows:

```lisp
number  list           new list
---------------------------------------------
c       nil            ((c 1))
b       ((c 1))        ((b 1)(c 1))
b       ((b 1)(c 1))   ((b 2)(c 1))
a       ((b 2)(c 1))   ((a 1)(b 2)(c 1))
```

`REDUCE` being defined for sequences, the compression function is generic:

```lisp
;; string
(compress "aaddzadzaaaddb")
=> ((#\a 2) (#\d 2) (#\z 1) (#\a 1) (#\d 1) (#\z 1) (#\a 3) (#\d 2) (#\b 1))

;; vector
(compress #(1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 55 5 5 5 5 5 5 ))
=> ((1 1) (2 1) (3 4) (4 3) (55 1) (5 6))

;; list
(compress '(1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 55 5 5 5 5 5 5 ))
=> ((1 1) (2 1) (3 4) (4 3) (55 1) (5 6))
```

Comment: Your implementation is certainly more concise and elegant. Starting from the end you avoid having to reverse after compressing, which doesn't reduces the time complexity, but saves an O(n) operation, and depending of how reduces is implemented (gotta check it), saves also memory space. This function is really interesting. We could implement integer partition algorithms, for instance, much more easily, what would be a bit painful in C (which also have its virtues). The fact is: the more I know Lisp, the more I like it. Thank you for your rich contribution

Comment: @GiovanniOliveira Thanks. About reduce, there was an interesting article called "Processing List Elements in Reverse Order", by Irène Durand and Robert Strandh

Comment: @GiovanniOliveira It might not save an O(n) operation, since the `:from-end` option might be implemented by reversing the list before operating on it in the usual forward direction.

Comment: @coredump this article is really impressive. Besides presenting a really efficient method to process lists in reverse order (which becomes a serious problem when you're handling a big volume of data), it shows a a good point for justify why and when we shoud use recursive functions in some circumstances. Thank you again

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million I think it could be related to which version and dialect of List are you building your code. As soon as I can, I'll take a look at sources and try to make some experimental tests.